# Transfer files from maintenance shell

Tags: usb, mount, rsync, transfer

I am running ubuntu 14.04.

I attempted to boot my computer and I received the following error:

```
General error mounting filesystems.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate this shell and reboot the system
```

Since the computer won't boot, I need to transfer for files. I can access the files from the command line but I can't teansfer any files.

I tried to mount the usb drive but the 'mount' is not installed.

I then used `rsync -avh /dev/sdb /media/usb`

error message:

```
rsync: mknod "/media/usb" failed: Read-only file system (30)
```

I am not tied to this method. I just need to transfer my files.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: It's often easier to resolve the mount error(s) than to rescue data the hard way. So maybe make a new question providing details about those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing things the hard way you can just start a live Linux system from USB or CD/DVD and rescue your data with that. It would also make the diagnosis of the mount error(s) more convenient.

If you really want or need to use the rescue shell,

- look for a writeable file system like `/run` or `/tmp` (look at the mount options in the output of `mount` or the content of `/proc/mounts` for suitable ones) or
- create a writeable tmpfs mount point yourself (`mount -t tmpfs none /tmp`).

There you can create directories you can later use as mount points for the file system(s) containing your data and those on your transfer medium. You should use the `--read-only` flag of `mount` on the former as to not alter or delete any data accidentally.

Comment: I ended up booting from a usb and accessing all my data